# Vue Volar in VSCode doesn't show full type errors

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, volar

I've been trying to develop an app in Vue with VSCode. For some reason, Volar refuses to show details of any type errors. It will only show that types are incompatible, but it will not drilldown into the properties to say why.

[Difference between normal Typescript and Volar error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBKSV.png)

**File content (same in .vue and .ts files):**

```
interface Bar {
  field: string;
}
interface Foo {
  field: string | undefined;
}

function processBar(f: Bar) {
  return f;
}

const foo: Foo = { field: 'foo' };
processBar(foo);
```

**Expected behavior (.ts file)**

- Typechecking shows *why* `Foo` is unassignable to parameter of type `Bar`.

```
Argument of type 'Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Bar'.
  Types of property 'field' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

**Actual behavior (.vue file)**

- Typechecking only shows *that* the types are incompatible

```
Argument of type 'Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Bar'.
  Types of property 'field' are incompatible.
```